# RESTful Web Service is working in the localhost server but not in the production server

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, cors

We have a web services application created in Java(Jersey + Jackson) with Apache Tomcat 7 as our server.  When we deployed it locally, everything is fine but when we deployed it in our production server, it doesn't work.  I did some research and some of them suggest that I should enable the **cross-origin resource sharing** (CORS) either in the **web.xml** or create a class that filters the CORS.  I did both but the result is still the same.

Any help is highly appreciated.  :)  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the production server logs indicate that the request is being received and properly dispatched?

Does using `curl` or `wget` as your client help illuminate the problem? Alternatively, what does Firebug or Chrome dev tools show in the "Network" tab when the request is made? Or, is there a console log in the browser that helps?

Comment: As @TommyKnowlton mentioned, what did you debug? What's the HTTP response you get? When you say production, it means that you are not testing it as http://localhost and something like http://yourdomain.com. Virtual hosts etc are taken care I believe. Did you try to list the WADL?

Answer (score 0):

My colleague have already fixed our problem.  It's kind a weird but it solves when he upgraded the version of JVM from 1.7 to 1.8 in our server.

I don't know if this is okay, but I will try to do some research and check if this is really valid.

@Tommy Knowlton and @Karthik R, thank you very much for your time reading my question.  :)